# How to validate a epub file with OPF more than 300KB?

Tags: epub

Am having an Epub with 110 html files and more than 7000 images.
I have reduced the file names by giving page breaks in CSS.
Also i have changed images name with minimum characters only.

```
<item id="f0001-01" href="f0001-01.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/></manifest>
```

by

```
<item id="i1" href="i1.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/></manifest>
```

Still my OPF size exceeds 300kb. How can i solve this problem?

Is there any Possibility of using two OPF's in a single ePub?

Comment: The EPUB specification does not impose any size limit on any file inside the OCF container (i.e., the ZIP file). The "300 KB" max size was a constraint of certain eReaders, which were unable to open XHTML files above 300 KB. So, in theory there should be no problem in including an OPF file so large. Of course, readers that actually read and store in memory the OPF file contents, might struggle to open your EPUB --- but that's an issue with the implementations, not the EPUB spec per se.

Comment: Is there any Possibility of using two OPF's in a single ePub?

Comment: It would seem not. http://www.idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPF_2.0.1_draft.htm#Section1.4.1.2: `"i. it includes a single OPF Package Document [...]"`